# Xml File Creation in C# using Xml To Linq

Tags: c#, xml

I've an xml file(Sample.xml) which has the following structure

```
 <Root>
    <Child ChildName="Ms_7">
            <MissingSiblings>
                <Sibling SiblingName="47" />
            </MissingSiblings>
    </Child>
    <Child ChildName="Ms_8">
            <MissingSiblings>
                 <Sibling SiblingName="P2" />
            </MissingSiblings>
     </Child>
     <Child ChildName="Ms_9">
            <MissingSiblings>
                 <Sibling SiblingName="T2" />
            </MissingSiblings>
    </Child>
    <Child ChildName="Ms_10">
            <MissingSiblings>
                <Sibling SiblingName="R3" />
            </MissingSiblings>
    </Child>
    <Child ChildName="Additional_SIB1">
            <AdditionalSiblings>
                 <Sibling SiblingName="92" />
                 <Sibling SiblingName="93" />
            </AdditionalSiblings>
        <MissingSiblings>
                <Sibling SiblingName="S3" />
            </MissingSiblings>
    </Child>
    <Child ChildName="Additional_SIB2">
            <AdditionalSiblings>
                <Sibling SiblingName="39" />
                <Sibling SiblingName="34" />
            </AdditionalSiblings>
    </Child>  
</Root>
```

i need to update another xml file(Result.xml) from the Sample.xml file .
 like

```
<Root>
    <Step Name="Step1" Date="06/12/2010" Value="">
        <Test Name="Ms_7" AdditionalSibling="" MissingSibling="47"/>
        <Test Name="Ms_8" AdditionalSibling="" MissingSibling="P2"/>
        <Test Name="Ms_9" AdditionalSibling="" MissingSibling="T2"/>
        <Test Name="Ms_10" AdditionalSibling="" MissingSibling="R3"/>
        <Test Name="SIB1" AdditionalSibling="92,93" MissingSibling="S3"/>
        <Test Name="SIB2" AdditionalSibling="39,34" MissingSibling=""/>
    </Step>
</Root>
```

Now i'm using like:

1) iterating through the contents of the Sample.xml file

2) Checking whether the "ChildName" Contains"Additional"

a)Removing temporarly

3) Iterating through child nodes

4) if more than one child appending a comma(,)

the code is as follows:

```
        XmlDocument SampleDoc = new XmlDocument();
        XmlDocument ResultDoc = new XmlDocument();

        SampleDoc.Load(Application.StartupPath + "\\Sample.xml");
        ResultDoc.Load(Application.StartupPath + "\\Result.xml");
        XmlElement ResultRoot = ResultDoc.DocumentElement;
        XmlElement RsNxt = (XmlElement)ResultDoc.SelectSingleNode("//Step[@Name='Step222']");
        if (RsNxt == null)
            RsNxt=ResultDoc.CreateElement("Step");
        else
            RsNxt.RemoveAll();
        RsNxt.SetAttribute("Name", "Step1");
        RsNxt.SetAttribute("Date", DateTime.Now.ToString());
        RsNxt.SetAttribute("Value", "");
        String l_strName = "";
        XmlNodeList ChildList = SampleDoc.SelectNodes("//Root/Child");
        if (ChildList.Count > 0)
        {
            foreach (XmlNode child in ChildList)
            {
                XmlElement ChildElement = (XmlElement)child;
                l_strName = ChildElement.GetAttribute("ChildName");

                bool l_bvalue = l_strName.Contains("Additional");
                int l_ntemp = 0;
                XmlNodeList l_List = null;
                String l_strAdd = "";
                String l_strMissing = "";

                String l_strAdditional = l_strName;
                if (l_bvalue == true)
                    l_strAdditional = l_strName.Substring(l_strName.IndexOf('_') + 1);

                XmlElement Test = ResultDoc.CreateElement("Test");
                Test.SetAttribute("Name", l_strAdditional);
                if (l_bvalue == false)
                {
                    l_List = ChildElement.SelectNodes("//Child[@ChildName='" + l_strName + "']/MissingSiblings/Sibling"); 

                    l_ntemp = 0;
                    String l_strMissingSibling = "";
                    foreach (XmlNode l_missingS in l_List)
                    {
                        XmlElement Element = (XmlElement)l_missingS;
                        l_strMissingSibling = Element.GetAttribute("SiblingName");
                        l_ntemp += 1;
                        if (l_ntemp == 1)
                            l_strMissing = l_strMissingSibling;
                        if (l_ntemp > 1)
                        {
                            l_strMissing += ',' + " ";
                            l_strMissing += l_strMissingSibling;
                        }
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    l_List = ChildElement.SelectNodes("//Child[@ChildName='" + l_strName +"']/AdditionalSiblings/Sibling");
                    l_ntemp = 0;
                    String l_strAddSibling = "";
                    foreach (XmlNode Additional in l_List)
                    {
                        XmlElement nodeElement = (XmlElement)Additional;
                        l_strAddSibling = nodeElement.GetAttribute("SiblingName");
                        l_ntemp += 1;
                        if (l_ntemp == 1)
                            l_strAdd = l_strAddSibling;
                        if (l_ntemp > 1)
                        {
                            l_strAdd += ',' + " ";
                            l_strAdd += l_strAddSibling;
                        }
                    }
                }
                Test.SetAttribute("AdditionalSiblings", l_strAdd);
                Test.SetAttribute("MissingSiblings", l_strMissing);
                RsNxt.AppendChild(Test);
            }

        }
        ResultRoot.AppendChild(RsNxt);
        ResultDoc.Save(Application.StartupPath + "\\Result.xml");
```

Is there any other way to do this like  Xml to Linq approch?

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can surely be simplified using Linq to XML. I wrote a short example for your case, you need to add some details (like handling missing siblings too), but it should give you an idea. The `XDocument doc` should contain the original XML.

```
XDocument newDoc = new XDocument(new XElement("step"));
foreach (XElement child in doc.Root.Elements())
{
    XElement entry = new XElement("Test");
    entry.SetAttributeValue("Name", child.Attribute("ChildName")
                                         .Value.Replace("Additional_", ""));

    if (child.Elements("AdditionalSiblings").Count() > 0)
    {
        entry.SetAttributeValue("AdditionalSibling",
            child.Elements("AdditionalSiblings").Elements()
                                                .Select(xe => xe.Attribute("SiblingName").Value)
                                                .Aggregate((s1,s2) => s1+","+s2));
    }
    else
    {
        entry.SetAttributeValue("AdditionalSibling", "");
    }
    newDoc.Root.Add(entry);

}
```

Comment: Thank you... I need to remove" Additional" from "Additional_SIB1" and then to create the child node with the attribute value 'Name="SIB1"'

Comment: @ Jens : it will throw the exception if the name does not contain "Additional"